# How does bracket notation works when returning object's value

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I have an object:

```
var contacts = [
{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
}
];
```

Now I have for loop and after I'm returning property's value by writing:

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){

for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {

if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName) {
if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
  return contacts[i][prop];
```

contacts[i][prop] is returning given property value, like  "number": "0487345643", but what I don't understand is, why it's returning value of property if we say return contacts[i][prop] when prop means property and not value. What should we say then to get a property and not its value? How this all bracket notation thing works? It was always confusing for me.

Comment: `prop` is simply a variable name, it could be `turtles` and still return the value. Bracket notation means supplying a string value in the brackets that matches the property name in the object.

Comment: example: `contacts[i].firstName` = `contacts[i]["firstName"]`

Comment: Oh, so by using brackets we just say property name and it gives us back its value?

Comment: @BenG so contacts[i].prop is the same as contacts[i][prop]? Both returns value of property?

Comment: if `prop` is a variable with the value `"prop"` then yes.

Comment: @BenG prop is an argument in my function. I pass it a value when I call my function later on. For example: `lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");` But I think arguments in functions acts like a placeholder or variable, so the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bracket notation is useful when you need to access an object's value but you don't know exactly which property you're going to be using.

For example:

```
var obj = {
    a: 'test',
    b: 'home'
};
//bracket notation
//define a string prop
var prop = 'a';

//then later we can use prop to access a value
console.log(obj[prop]); //prints 'test'

//its exactly the same as doing this:
console.log(obj['a']); //prints 'test'

//dot notation works when you know the property name
console.log(obj.b); //prints 'home'
```

In your function, a user can specify a property name `prop`. Below I am passing `'number'` and `'lastName'` to the function.

```
console.log(lookUpProfile('Sherlock', 'number')); //prints '0487345643'
console.log(lookUpProfile('Akira', 'lastName')); //prints 'Laine'
```

Comment: Oh, now I get it. So bracket notation is more dynamic. It's handy when working with functions, coz everytime you can specify  a different property name. And placeholder (argument) "prop" can be reusable many times. Thanks!

Comment: Correct, bracket notation is for dynamically accessing a property, while dot notation is for when you know the property name.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the property name is on prop variable. With brackets you accessing to properties by their names. So, if your code is obj[prop] you actually says to interpreter "I want to get from obj value by key stored in prop variable"

Comment: Okay, but how my function's argument (prop) understands that I need to return exactly object's property value and not something else? When we call the function and pass it a value like: lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes"); it realises that prop is "likes" or any other property? Argument in function acts like a variable and then we give it a value when we call the function, right?

Comment: Data in objects presented as key-value pairs and key is just a string. For example in object {a: 1, b: 2} a and b are keys so to get the value asociated with a key you can use obj.a or obj['a'], but you also can use variable key. For example

Comment: var prop = 'a';

Comment: var value = obj[prop];

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. So in my case by using bracket notation and "prop" argument we just make it easy to pass it different property names outside the function when we call it. It's more handy way and code can be reusable many times with different arguments.